# What are traps?

Tags: embedded, cpu, microcontroller, processor, hardware-traps

There are many different types of ***traps*** listed in processor datasheets, e.g. BusFault, MemManage Fault, Usage Fault and Address Error.

What is their purpose? How can they be utilized in fault handling?

Comment: what processor is this? Cortex-M3?

Comment: I see this is a clarification of another question and is a Cortex-M3.

Answer (score 16):

Traps are essentially subroutine calls that are forced by the processor when it detects something unusual in your stream of instructions.  (Some processors make them into interrupts, but that's mostly just pushing more context onto the stack; this gets more interesting if the trap includes a switch between user and system address spaces).

This is useful for handling conditions that occur rarely but need to be addressed, such as division by zero.  Normally, it is useless overhead to have an extra pair of instructions to test the divisor for zero before executing a divide instruction, since the divisor is never expected to be zero.  So the architects have the processor do this check in parallel with the actual divide as part of the divide instruction, and cause the processor to trap to a divide-by-zero routine if the divisor is zero.  Another interesting case is illegal-memory-address; clearly, you don't want to have to code a test to check each address before you use it.

Often there are a variety of fault conditions of potential interest and the processor by design will pass control to a different trap routine (often set up as a vector) for each different type of fault.

Once the processor has a trap facility, the CPU architects find lots of uses.  A common use is debugger breakpoints, and trap-to-OS for the purposes of executing a operating system call.

Answer (score 8):

Microprocessors have traps for various fault conditions. They are synchronous interrupts that allow the running OS / software to take appropriate action on the error. Traps interrupt program flow and set register bits to indicate the fault. Debugger breakpoints are also implemented using traps.

In a typical computing environment, the operating system takes care of CPU traps triggered by user processes. Let's consider what happens when I run the following program:

```
int main(void)
{
    volatile int a = 1, b = 0;
    a = a % b; /* div by zero */
    return 0;
}
```

An error message was displayed, and my box is still running like nothing happened. My operating system's approach to fault handling in this case was to kill the offending process and inform the user with the error message `Floating point exception`.

> Traps in kernel mode are more problematic. It is not as strightforward for the OS to take corrective action if it is itself at fault. For a system process there is no underlying layer of protection. This is why faulty device drivers can cause real problems.

When working on bare metal, without the comforting protection of an operating system, the situation is much similar to the one above. Number one objective for achieving continuous *and* correct operation is to catch all potential trap conditions *before they get to trigger any traps*, using assertions and higher-level error handlers. ***Consider traps as the last line of defense, a safety net you don't intentionally want to fall into.***

Defining behaviors for trap handlers is worth some thought, even if they *"should never happen"*. They will be executed when things go wrong in an *unanticipated* manner, be it due to cosmic rays altering RAM in the most extreme case. Unfortunately, there is no single correct answer to what error handlers should do.

Code Complete, 2nd ed:

> The style of error processing that is most appropriate depends on the kind of software the error occurs in and generally favors more *correctness* or more *robustness*. Strictly speaking, these terms are at opposite ends of the scale from each other. Correctness means never returning an inaccurate result; no result is better than an inaccurate result. Robustness means always trying to do something that will allow the software to keep operating, even if that leads to results that are inaccurate sometimes.

Clearly, my operating system's fault handling is designed with robustness in mind; I can execute flawed code and do pretty much anything without crashing the system. Designing solely for robustness would mean a recovery attempt whenever possible, and if all else fails, reset. This is a suitable approach if your product is e.g. a toy.

Safety critical applications need a bit more paranoia and should favor correctness instead; when a fault is detected, write error log, shutdown. We don't want our radiation therapy unit to pick dosage levels from invalid garbage values.

Comment: I don't understand you asking a question, and then providing a pretty complete answer within minutes.  Is this rep whoring?

Comment: @IraBaxter, This was originally intended as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860565/what-are-the-most-reliable-fault-handling-strategies), which was closed. The question was partially valid, although overly broad, so I decided to post this similar question better suited for the SO format. I also felt that my already complete answer to a closed question wouldn't benefit anyone if I just put it in the drawer, so here it is.

Comment: @IraBaxter, whoring is not the exact term Jeff uses in his [blog entry on this subject](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I wonder why people get so agitated over someone answering their own question.

Answer (score 4):

The ARMv7-M (not to be confused with the ARM7 nor the ARMv7-A) Cortex-M3 technical reference manual, which may also be part of one of the new ARM ARMs (ARM Architectural Reference Manual)
has a section describing each one of these faults.

Now the whys versus the whats are perhaps at the root of the question.  The why is usually so you have a chance to recover.  Imagine your set-top box or telephone that hits one of these do you want it to hang or if possible try to recover?  Unless you are expecting one of these faults (which in this context you shouldnt be, x86 systems and some of their faults are a completely different story) if you survive long enough to hit one of these you would most likely end up pulling the trigger on yourself (the software trying to kill itself by resetting the processor/system).  You can go through the long list and try to find ones you can recover from.  Divide by zero, how is the exception handler to know what the math mistake is that lead to this?  In general it cant.  Unaligned load or store, how is the handler to know what that code was trying to do, like divide by zero it is probably a software bug.  Undefined instruction, the code went into the weeds and executed data most likely by this point you are already too far gone and couldnt recover.  Any kind of memory bus fault the handler cannot repair the hardware.

You have to go through every fault, and for each fault define how you are going to handle it, all the ways you could have gotten to that one fault and the ways you can get out or handle each one of those paths.  On occasion you might be able to recover, otherwise you need a default action, hang the processor in an infinite loop in the handler for example so that the software engineer, if available, can try to use a debugger to get in and find where the code stopped.  Or have a watchdog timer, inside or outside the chip depending on the chip and board design (often outside the chip the WDT will reset the whole board).  You might have some non-volatile memory that you attempt to store the fault in, before letting or causing the reset, the time and code it takes to do that might lead you to another fault depending on what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, they allow you to execute code when something happens in the processor.  They're sometimes used by the OS for error recovery.